# How to show Cantor set is dense-in-itself?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, cantor-set

Here is my attempt to the proof. 
Suppose $x\in C$. Then we can find another element $x_n\in C$ such that $|x-x_n|<\frac{1}{3^n}<\epsilon$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by letting $x_n$ to be one of the endpoint of construction of Cantor set at stage $n$ . This eventually forms a sequence of $\{x_n\}$ such that this sequence converges to $x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, $x$ is not isolated. Since $x$ is arbitrary, it follows by definition that Cantor set is dense-in-itself.

Comment: Any topological space is dense in itself.

Comment: @Shalop "A linguist would be shocked to learn that 'E is dense in E' does not mean the same thing as 'E is [dense in itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself)'." (c) Littlewood, Mathematician's Miscellany

Comment: That's why it should be spelled "dense-in-itself" instead of "dense in itself"!

Comment: @Christoph I think it's just more clear to simply talk about *dense topological spaces* and *dense subsets*. This avoids any kind of confusion.

Comment: @Christoph topologists also call a space without isolated points "crowded".

Comment: Note that each $x_n$ can be chosen to be one of the end-points of the intervals at stage $n$ of the construction (and all these endpoints are in the eventual intersection)

Comment: @Christoph. That's why German is a nice language for math. You can make a compound word by sticking any string of words together. English grammar is slippery, resulting in ambiguities. "A nice red rose": Is the redness nice, or is the rose nice? A quasi-German  would be (1) A NiceRed Rose or (2) A Nice  RedRose.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I know, I'm german ;-) — In this case it would be "Eine schön rote Rose" versus "Eine schöne rote Rose", so it doesn't involve compound words but a distinction between adjectives and adverbs in their grammatical case.

Comment: @Christoph. Yes, another advantage. English has been called "an almost grammarless language".

Answer (score 2):

That's the way to prove it. Simply, since it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the topology we shall connsider in the Cantor set is the subspace topology, i.e. we will say a subset $U$ of the Cantor set $C$ is **open** if, and only if there exists some open $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $U=V\cap\mathbb{R}$

In this context, $C$ is a dense space if for any $x\in C$ and any open neighborhood of $x$ in $C$, it will always contain points of $C$ other than $x$, or in other words, $U\setminus\{x\}\cap C\not=\varnothing$ for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in C.

So, compare this with what you have proved. For a fixed $x\in C$, the elements $|x-y|<\epsilon$ with $y\in C$, $\epsilon>0$ form a basic neighborhood system of $x$ in the subspace topology, so in fact, to prove that the Cantor set is dense, you only have to check that any **basic open neighborhood** of any point $x\in C$ contains points of $C$ other than $x$.

In the end, your answer is correct, because by definition, if a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq C$ converges to a point $x\in C$, every basic open neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $C$ other than $x$; a certain tail $(x_n)_{n\geq N}$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

I hope my comment provides some further insight about why your answer is correct.

Comment: So, is my answer rigorous enough ? Or I need to add on something to make it rigorous?

Comment: Your answer is somewhat short, but I think it's fine. Just recall that a set is dense if all of its points are cluster (or limit) points, and that in the ternary Cantor set, if $x\in C$, then $x\in C_n$ where $C_n$ is a closed interval with length $1/3^n$, for any non-negative integer $n$; or in other words, $x$ shall be contained in one of the intervals defined iteratively by dividing into three parts then removing the middle one, at the $n$th step, for arbitrary $n$. All these points are implicit in your argument, but not stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Method $1.$ Show that the Cantor set $C$ is the set of those $x\in [0,1]$ that can be represented in ternary (Base-$3$) without using the digit $1$. E.g. in ternary, $1=0.\overline 2.$

Now if $\epsilon >0$ and $x\in C$ and in ternary $x=0.x_1x_2x_3...$ where each $x_j\in \{0,2\},$ then take $n$ large enough that $2\cdot 3^{-n}<\epsilon.$ And let $y_j=x_j$ when $j\ne n,$ while $y_n=2-x_n.$ Then the ternary sequence $0.y_1y_2y_3...$ represents a number $y\in C.$

And $0<|x-y|=2\cdot 3^{-n}<\epsilon.$

Method $2$. Consider the set $J$ of pair-wise disjoint open intervals thet are "removed" from $[0,1]$ to form $C.$ That is, $C=[0,1]\setminus (\cup J).$ The "removal" is often  described as a sequence of stages: At Stage 1, one interval $(1/3,2/3)$ is removed. At Stage  2, two intervals $(1/9,2/9),(7/9,8/9)$ are removed. At Stage $n$ there are $2^{n-1}$ intervals removed.

Show by induction on the "Stage number" $n$ that no two members of $J$ share a common end-point. And now:

$(i).$ Suppose by contradiction that $x$ is an isolated member of $C$ and $0<x<1.$

Then for some $r>0$ the intervals $(-r+x,x)$ and $(x,x+r)$ are subsets of $\cup J.$ And since the members of $J$ are pairwise-disjoint open intervals, there must exist positive $r',r''$ such that $(-r+x,x)\subseteq (-r',x)=j'\in J$ and $(x,x+r)\subseteq  (x,x+r'')=j''\in J.$ But then $x$ is a common end-point of $j'$ and $j'',$ a contradiction.

$(ii).$ The members of $J$ are pairwise-disjoint so the end-points of all the members of $J$ are  all in $C.$ And for every $n\in \Bbb N$ the points $3^{-n}$ and $1-3^{-n}$ are end-points of some members of $J.$ So neither $0$ nor $1$ is an isolated point of $C$.